# Java - Put the content of a txt file in a String using Scanner class

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have an example txt file:

```
This is an
example file.
```

I want to put the content of this file in a String using Scanner class. I resolved this problem as it follows:

```java
try
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("example.txt"));
    String fileContent = new String();
    int i = 0;
    while(s.hasNextLine())
    {
        if(i !=0) 
        {
            fileContent += "\n";
        }
        fileContent += s.nextLine();
        i++;
    }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{

}
```

If I didn't put that line on the if:

```java
fileContent += "\n";
```

I will get a string that begins with `\n` and that's not what I want, because I want to have the **same** content of the file in the fileContent string.

There is a better way to do what I want? Is important to me to use the Scanner class.

Thanks!

Comment: Not if you use `Scanner`.

Comment: You really should use a `StringBuilder` for this kind of "string accumulation" operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like If all you need a String, you could try something like:

```
String content = s.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: Using the code on the first block will add a \n at the end of the string, I tried it before.

Comment: Use the above instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use else block like this -

```
while(s.hasNextLine()){

    if(i !=0){
        fileContent += "\n";
    }else{
       fileContent += s.nextLine();
    }
    i++;
 }
```

It will remove the first newline from the `String`.

Comment: I'm looking for a better solution, this solution is similar to the one I wrote.